# Batman Arkham-verse timeline from the timeline site

Tags: dc, batman, chronological-order, arkham-series

Since the timeline site is pending or for renewal, it's kinda hard for me to know the timeline for this game, even the comics helped out. Can someone help me by telling me the chronological order with the comics and games from the timeline site?

Comment: What timeline site are you talking about? And you are looking for the comics directly tied to the Arkham games? Because I believe they are an alternate continuity.

Comment: There is a timeline at https://arkhamcity.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline

Comment: There was a timeline for a site for it like there was for dead space. Where do you think the guy got it from? And yes for the comics relating to them.

Comment: Do you have the URL? If so, we could probably pull the cached site.

Comment: https://thetimelinesite.com › batman-arkham-verse

Comment: Try https://web.archive.org/web/20190212180504/http://thetimelinesite.com/batman-arkham-verse

Answer (score 1):

From [this timeline](https://arkhamcity.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline) (some of the reasoning is described on that site, not quoted here for brevity)

> ### Year 1
>
> *Batman - Arkham Origins: Initiation*
>
> ### Year 2
>
> #### ?
>
> *Batman - Arkham Origins #1-8*
>
> #### December
>
> **24 - 25**
>
> *Batman: Arkham Origins*
>
> **31**
>
> *Batman: Arkham Origins: Cold, Cold Heart*
>
> ### Year 3
>
> #### March-April
>
> *Batman: Arkham Origins Blackgate*
>
> #### September
>
> Arkham Asylum is reinstated.
>
> ### Year 4
>
> #### June
>
> Dick Grayson loses his parents during an acrobatics show and is taken in as Bruce Wayne's ward.
>
> #### August
>
> *Batman Arkham Knight - Batgirl Begins #1*
>
> #### October
>
> Dick Grayson becomes Robin.
>
> ### Year 5
>
> #### November
>
> *Batman: Arkham Origins Multiplayer*
>
> ### Year 6
>
> #### February
>
> Dick Grayson quits being Robin, moves to Blüdhaven.
>
> #### March
>
> Dick Grayson becomes Nightwing.
>
> #### May
>
> Dick Grayson gets a job at BPD as a Police Officer.
>
> #### June
>
> *Batman Arkham Knight - Batgirl/Harley Quinn #1*
>
> *Batman Arkham Knight - Batgirl/Harley Quinn #2*
>
> #### September
>
> *Batman: Assault on Arkham*
>
> #### December
>
> Batman catches Jason Todd stealing the Batmobile's tires.
>
> ### Year 7
>
> #### March
>
> Jason Todd becomes Robin.
>
> #### October
>
> Robin (Jason Todd) goes after the Joker alone and is captured and tied up in an abandoned wing of Arkham Asylum.
>
> ### Year 8
>
> #### March
>
> Tim Drake reveals to Batman he knows he's Bruce Wayne.
>
> #### June
>
> Tim Drake becomes Robin.
>
> #### October
>
> Batman receives the video of Jason Todd being "killed".
>
> ### Year 9
>
> #### February
>
> *Batgirl: A Matter of Family*
>
> #### August
>
> Barbara Gordon (Batgirl) is crippled by The Joker.
>
> #### November
>
> Barbara Gordon takes on the persona of Oracle.
>
> ### Year 10
>
> Poison Ivy releases thousands of poisonous spores into Gotham, killed hundreds of people.
>
> ### Year 11
>
> #### July
>
> *Batman - The Road to Arkham #1*
> *Batman: Arkham Asylum*
>
> *Batman - Arkham City #1, "Ruins"*
> *Batman - Arkham City:  Chapter 1, "Hugo Strange"*
> *Batman - Arkham City #2, "Breaking Ground"*
>
> #### September
>
> *Batman - Arkham City:  Chapter 2, "Cut and Run"*
> *Batman - Arkham City #3, "Choosing Sides"*
> *Batman - Arkham City:  Chapter 3, "Riddle Me"*
> *Batman - Arkham City #4, "A Night on the Town"* 
> *Batman - Arkham City #5, "Exposure"* 
> *Batman - Arkham City:  Chapter 4, "Guardian Angel"*
>
> #### October
>
> *Batman - Arkham City:  Chapter 5, "Fall of the Titan"*       
> *Batman - Arkham City:  Chapter 6,  "Three's a Crowd"*       
> *Batman - Arkham City:  Chapter 7,  "Moving at a Glacial Pace"*
>
> ### Year 12
>
> #### December
>
> 21
>
> *Batman - Arkham City: Catwoman (Prologue)*
> *Batman: Arkham City*
> *Batman - Arkham City:  Catwoman (Ending)*
>
> 22
>
> *Batman - Arkham Knight #1*
> *Batman - Arkham City:  End Game #1*
>
> #### January
>
> 3
>
> *Batman - Arkham City:  End Game #2 (1-16)*
> *Batman: Arkham City: Harley Quinn's Revenge (Flashbacks)*
>
> 5
>
> *Batman: Arkham City: Harley Quinn's Revenge (Present Day)*
> *Batman - Arkham City:  End Game #2 (17-23)*
> *Batman - Arkham City:  End Game #3-6*
>
> #### February
>
> *Batman - Arkham Knight #2*
>
> #### March
>
> *Batman - Arkham Knight #3-6*
> *Batman - Arkham Knight #7 (Safe House)*
>
> #### March-April
>
> *Batman Arkham Knight: The Riddler's Gambit*
>
> #### September
>
> *Batman - Arkham Knight: Robin Special*
> *Batman - Arkham Knight #7 (Who Wants To Kill A Billionaire - Part One)*
> *Batman - Arkham Knight #8-10*
>
> #### October
>
> *Batman - Arkham Knight: Annual*
> *Batman - Arkham Knight: Harley Quinn Story Pack*
> *Batman - Arkham Knight #0*
>
> Thursday 30
>
> *Batman - Arkham VR*
>
> **Friday 31**
>
> *Batman: Arkham Knight*
> *Batman - Arkham Knight: The Season of Infamy*
>
> #### November
>
> 1st
>
> *Catwoman's Revenge|Batman - Arkham Knight: Catwoman's Revenge*
>
> #### November/December
>
> *Batman - Arkham Knight: Red Hood Story Pack*
> *Batman - Arkham Knight: GCPD Lockdown*
> *Batman - Arkham Knight: A Flip of a Coin*

The timeline site that you've clarified this to be can be read via the Wayback Machine [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190212180504/http://thetimelinesite.com/batman-arkham-verse). I'm not quite up to transcribing all of the formatting into another quote.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Version of the Chronology i use

BATMAN ARKHAM SERIES

Batman: Arkham Knight [I]- #15, "Bane of Existence, Part 2"  (pg. 1, 2)

Batman- Arkham Knight:  Genesis #1  (pg. 12-14)

Batman- Arkham Unhinged #21, "Crocodile Tears"  (pg. 3-11)

Batman: Arkham Origins (Initiation)                              DLC

Batman- Arkham Origins #1-8                 Interactive Novel

Batman: Arkham Origins                               Video Game

Batman: Arkham Origins (Cold, Cold, Heart)                   DLC

Batman: Black Gate                                   Video Game

Batman Arkham Knight - Batgirl Begins #1

Arkham Knight- Batgirl and Harley Quinn 1 & 2

Batman- Arkham Unhinged #8, "Ruffled Feathers"  (pg. 3-20)

Batman- Arkham Unhinged #38, 39 "Beloved Start at page 7

Batman: Assault on Arkham                                 Animated Movie

Batman- Arkham Knight:  Genesis #1  (pg. 15-22)

Batman- Arkham Knight:  Genesis #2  (pg. 8-11, 13-19)

Batman- Arkham Knight:  Genesis #3  (pg. 9-19)

Batman- Arkham Knight:  Genesis #4  (pg. 3, 4, 12-21)

Batman- Arkham City:  End Game #1  (pg. 31-40)

Batgirl: A Matter of Family                              DLC

Batman- Arkham Unhinged #17, "Arkham City Sirens"

Batman- Arkham Unhinged #38, "Beloved"  (pg. 3-6)

Batman- Arkham Unhinged #39  “Beloved Pt. 3"  (pg. 3-22)

Batman: Arkham Asylum: The Road to Arkham #1

Batman: Arkham Asylum                                Video Game

Batman- Arkham Knight:  Genesis #5  (pg. 11-22)

Batman- Arkham City #1, "Ruins’

Batman- Arkham City: Digital Chapter 1, "Hugo Strange"

Batman- Arkham City:  Lockdown

Batman- Arkham City #2, "Breaking Ground"

Batman- Arkham Unhinged #44-58 "Welcome to the Slough of Despond

Batman- Arkham City: Digital Chapter 2, "Cut and Run"

Batman- Arkham City #3, "Choosing Sides"

Batman- Arkham City: Digital Chapter 3, "Riddle Me"

Batman- Arkham City #4, "A Night on the Town"

Batman- Arkham City #5, "Exposure"

Batman- Arkham City: Digital Chapter 4, "Guardian Angel"

Batman- Arkham City: Digital Chapter 5, "Fall of the Titan"

Batman- Arkham City: Digital Chapter 6,  "Three's a Crowd"

Batman- Arkham City: Digital Chapter 7,  "Moving at a Glacial Pace"

Batman- Arkham Unhinged #1-3, "Inside Job"

Batman- Arkham Unhinged #4-6, "Observations"

Batman- Arkham Unhinged #35-37, "Eviction Notice"

Batman- Arkham Knight #4, "The Last Will and Testament of the Joker"  (pg. 3-20)

Batman- Arkham City: Catwoman prologue

Batman: Arkham City (Stop after Joker leaves with Talia)

Batman- Arkham Knight:  Genesis #6  (pg. 9-17)

Continue Batman - Arkham City

Batman- Arkham City: Catwoman finish story

Batman- Arkham Knight [II] (pg. 22)

Batman- Arkham Knight [II] #1, "Death of a Rival" (pg. 1-16)

Batman- Arkham City: End Game #1

Batman- Arkham City: End Game #2 (1-16)

Batman - Arkham City: Harley Quinn's Revenge DLC

Batman- Arkham City: End Game #2 (17-23)

Batman- Arkham City: End Game #3-4

Batman- Arkham Knight #2

Batman- Arkham City: End Game #5-6

Batman- Arkham Knight #3-6

Batman - Arkham Knight: The Riddler's Gambit Book

Batman - Arkham Knight: Genesis #1-6 Comic

Batman - Arkham Knight: Robin Special #1, "The Apprentice

Batman- Arkham Knight #7-12

Batman - Arkham Knight: Annual #1 , "Fear City"

Batman- Arkham Knight: Harley Quinn DLC

Batman - Arkham Knight Game

The Season of Infamy DLC

Batman - Arkham Knight: Red Hood DLC

Batman - Arkham Knight: Catwoman's Revenge

Batman - Arkham Knight: GCPD Lockdown

Batman - Arkham Knight: A Flip of a Coin

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this is the chronological order? Also it's worth noting that you can [edit] your posts so you don't need multiple answers. You should delete your second answer and [edit] its contents into here instead since they are supposed to be one answer.

Comment: Every time a new game is released. I replay, reread, rewatch, everything in one of my chronologies. Not only Arkham, But God of War, Assassin's Creed/Watch_Dogs , DARKSIDERS, GEARS OF WAR, THE LAST OF US, the newer TOMB RAIDER Series, UNCHARTED Series and more. Trust me when i say that my obsessive compulsive nature leads me to do a great deal of research.